# Power failure during ssd TRIM: did it break my SSD?

Tags: ssd, hard-drive-failure, trim

I was doing a TRIM of my new 480gb SSD with Piriform's Defraggler. It was taking some time so I let it run for some hours while AFK, but a storm happened and my home had a power-failure. All my hardware and lights are OK, also my PC seems to be fine, but the SSD (which was almost empty) appears now to be full.

Fast conclusion is it couldn't end the TRIM process, and the power failure occurred while it was still working on it.

Now SSD (which I know was almost empty, I used 100/480gb on it) seems to be full if I look at it with any program:

[image: seem to be full]

Here are my S.M.A.R.T parameters:
[image: Here are my S.M.A.R.T parameters.]

Now the storage is usable, but often computer or programs get frozen and I have to reboot. Also, on reboot sometimes it doesn't find windows boot manager and boots to bios, but seems to be random and I can't reproduce it.

Is my SSD broken? Is there a way I can bring it back to its previous state without losing my data?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to defragment an SSD! All you are doing is shortening the life-time of your disk.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: It would help for you to understand that writing zeroes to the SSD is wasteful and damaging to the disk's lifetime. A real TRIM of the disk should take seconds. That's all I'm trying to helpfully convey here for the future.

Comment: @harrymc That's no longer true. First, modern SSDs have such a large write lifetime that the cost is negligible. Second, modern SSDs are IOPS limited rather than read/write bandwidth limited, and a contiguous file takes fewer I/Os to read (and contiguous empty space takes fewer I/Os to write in). As the cost of defragmenting an SSD has continued to go down, the benefits have continued to go up. It's now not at all clear that it's not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: IOPS have nothing to do with the aging of blocks, [Wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Wear_leveling) is the important factor which is per-block. I suggest reading [What are IOPS and should you care?](https://storageswiss.com/2015/02/23/what-are-iops-and-should-you-care/) and [Should You Or Should You Not Defrag An SSD](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/defrag-an-ssd.html). Or do you maintain that everybody is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

TRIM works independently of the file system on it.  This means if something messed up with a properly issued TRIM command to the drive, it wouldn't affect what the files look like on it.  (If the OS messes up and tells the drive to erase the wrong sectors, this is not an SSD issue but an OS or application issue)

If TRIM failed, you would run into issues like the drive not showing up or not being writable, or weird disk errors when trying to read/write/mount the drive, or simply nothing.  The exact behavior would be firmware dependent.

The good news is that your SSD is not broken.

Looking at [this](https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/defraggler/technical-information/defraggler-and-ssds), it seems like what's more likely happening is that Defraggler is "zero filling" your drive - this is accomplished by writing a file and filling it with zeros until the disk runs out of space.  According to that information, Defraggler does this if the SSD is not "TRIM-able".

Any new SSD should be TRIM-able, but here's a list of things that could make the OS believe otherwise even though the drive would support TRIM:

- Not having latest firmware on the SSD (dangerous if you do update firmware, can cause data loss)
- SSD being in a hardware or possibly motherboard-level RAID that isn't passing through TRIM commands.
- SSD being in a USB enclosure that isn't passing through TRIM commands.
- Full disk encryption software like Veracrypt, etc.
- Disk being used in a hypervisor environment like VMware or Hyper-V, though I think they all support and passthrough TRIM now.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the file that's using all the space. The tool does a "fake trim" by allocating all the space on the SSD for a file that it fills with zeroes and then deletes. It just didn't get a chance to delete that file.

Comment: just to add, [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) on Windows or baobab or kdirstat on Linux should work for finding this file.